# Как указать путь к своему редатору в select-editor?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu, mc

Хочу сделать [Textadept](https://orbitalquark.github.io/textadept) редактором по умолчанию в Xubuntu - как визуальным, так и терминальным.

Вот скачал я его и распаковал в `/opt`.

Затем создал лаунчер для `/opt/textadept/textadept` и ассоциировал его c `text/plain`, так что `thunar` открывает текстовые файлы этим редактором. Тут проблем нет.

Теперь мне нужно чтобы `mc` также считал его редактором и я не знаю как это сделать.

Когда я запускаю команду `sudo select-editor` или `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` (похоже они ничем не отличаются), там я могу выбрать, например `nano`, и `mc` будет использовать `nano`, но как **указать свой** я не знаю.

Пробовал создать символьную ссылку от `/opt/textadept/textadept-curses` к `/bin/editor` и теперь командой `editor` запускается не `nano`, а мой `textadept`, но `mc` по-прежнему редактирует файлы через `nano`.

Также я пробовал вот что:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

E_NAME=Textadept
E_PATH=/opt/textadept/textadept-curses

sudo update-alternatives --install $E_NAME $E_PATH 1111
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
sudo select-editor
```

Этот скрипт регистрирует мой редактор, он появляется в списке доступных, но по какой-то непонятной причине `select-editor` его не выбирает, просто игнорирует мой выбор!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

создайте файл `.selected_editor` в домашнем каталоге

```
SELECTED_EDITOR="/opt/textadept/textadept-curses"
```

в mc в меню "Настройки-Конфигурация" уберите галочку "Встроенный редактор"

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Этот файл у меня был создан автоматически, но вчера мне это никак не помогало, а сегодня чудом всё заработало! Видимо нужно было перезагрузиться (или проспаться ).